# Controlling the size of uiVideoPanel

Tags: webrtc, vline

I'm using the [vLine JavaScript API](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/) with the [uiVideoPanel widget](https://vline.com/developer/docs/ui_widgets) to make WebRTC video calls.

My code looks like this:

```js
window.vlineClient = client_ = 
  vline.Client.create({"serviceId": serviceId, "ui": true,
                       'uiVideoPanel':'showvideo'
});
```

and HTML:

```html
<div class='span5'
     style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color: #eeeeee;" 
     id='showvideo'>
</div>
```

However when one person calls another, the video takes up the full screen instead of only 300px by 300px.

How can I control the size of the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set the CSS `position` to `relative` or `absolute`.

For example, with the HTML you provided it would be:

```html
<div class='span5'
     style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color: #eeeeee; position: absolute;" 
     id='showvideo'>
</div>
```